# set timeout from property file in spring <tx:method tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions, spring-properties

I using transaction management and AOP as following:

```
<tx:advice id="tx.sys.advice" transaction-manager="sys.tx.mngr" >
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="suspendMember" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" timeout="10"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="domain.pointcut" expression="execution(* com.IUser.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="tx.sys.advice" pointcut-ref="domain.pointcut" />

    <aop:advisor advice-ref="tx.sys.advice" pointcut-ref="domain.pointcut"  />
</aop:config>
```

I set timeout to `10` but I want set it by a property at properties file.
I change my xml contetnt as following:

```
<tx:method name="suspendMember" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" timeout="${setting.timeout}"/>
```

with above change I get error in run time as following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from class path resource [context.xml] is invalid; 
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 116; 
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${setting.timeout}' is not a valid value for integer'
```

**EDIT**

my header of `context.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

and version of spring is : `3.0.5.RELEASE`

Comment: Which Spring version (or version of the xsds are you using). Post your file header (containing the xsd declarations) and the spring versions you are using.

Comment: @M.Deinum I edited my question.

Comment: The `timeout` property doesn't support expressions, it is defined as `xsd:int` or `xsd:integer` depending on the spring version.

Comment: Is there way for define transaction management by traditional define bean in spring . By this solution I can set timeout dynamically?

Comment: You could but I strongly advice against it as that would mean using old, basically, deprecated classes and will double your configuration efforts which make it easier to make mistakes and you will run in weird situations in which you get the non-transactional instead of transactional beans. If it is only for this method and this is a corner case go with a `TransactionTemplate` instead.